# My apps shut down immediately after opening it

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have develop my own apps and try to open it in emulator 5556. It is installed successfully.
However when I open it, it shut down immediately. I hope someone can help.
And here is my androidmainfest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.monkey"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission   android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x20000" android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="AIzaSyCi43x8rh1xwonf15SQ2faHLPKCJUkzAn8" />
    <activity android:theme="@*android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.example.monkey.Home" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.example.monkey.SettingPreferences" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="com.example.monkey.CategoryList" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="com.example.monkey.MenuList" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="com.example.monkey.MenuDetail" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="com.example.monkey.ShareMenu" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="com.example.monkey.Contact" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="com.example.monkey.News" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="com.example.monkey.NewsDetail" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="com.example.monkey.YourOrder" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="com.example.monkey.Reservation" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
</application>
```

```
03-16 13:01:14.249: D/AndroidRuntime(1138): Shutting down VM
03-16 13:01:14.249: W/dalvikvm(1138): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception       (group=0xb3a3aba8)
03-16 13:01:14.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1138): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-16 13:01:14.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1138): Process: com.example.monkey, PID: 1138
03-16 13:01:14.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1138): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to    instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.monkey/com.example.monkey.Home}:   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.monkey.Home" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.monkey-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.monkey-2, /system/lib]]
03-16 13:01:14.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
03-16 13:01:14.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
03-16 13:01:14.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-16 13:01:14.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
03-16 13:01:14.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-16 13:01:14.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-16 13:01:14.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-16 13:01:14.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-16 13:01:14.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-16 13:01:14.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-16 13:01:14.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-16 13:01:14.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-16 13:01:14.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1138): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.monkey.Home" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.monkey-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.monkey-2, /system/lib]]
03-16 13:01:14.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
03-16 13:01:14.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
03-16 13:01:14.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
03-16 13:01:14.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
03-16 13:01:14.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
03-16 13:01:14.419: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Can you post the Logcat's output so that we can help you?

Comment: and main activity too. `Home` I guess

Comment: Can you post your main activity's code?

Comment: whenever your app closes unexpectedly take a log at the logcat

Comment: I have added the logcat now. I am sorry i forgot to post it before asking the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, according to the Error Log, it's not finding the java code for your activity. Did you use an IDE to generate the activity? Please make sure that the class used for your activity has the SAME name. In your case, you HAVE to have a file called `Home.java` in your src folder. Can you confirm that it's there?

UPDATE: If you have difficulties getting the IDE to generate the code for your activity, try making your own file called Home.java and try this code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

public class Home extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.Home);
}

}
```

(Keep in mind that best naming practices state that layout names in android be: all lowercase, typically starting with "activity", and using "_" for spaces between words. Not a huge issue but it's good coding practice. Best of luck!

Comment: I have no idea why my src folder is empty. Can I regenerate those files as I remember those files are auto generate?

Comment: That's the cause then. If you're using and IDE like Eclipse, it's as easy as clicking File > New > Other. Open the Android directory and choose "Android Activity". Everything will be handled automatically from there. (Please keep in mind, that .java file is where you place all the functionality for your activities. Your app isn't going to do anything without you coding it. So make sure you know enough about Java to program your app.)

Comment: If you're still having issues, see my code example above in the original answer.